# How do I reset my iCloud credentials after entering an incorrect email address?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

While setting my new iPhone up I put in the incorrect e-mail by missing one letter. Now I can't get in to do anything! It won't let me reset as the email is wrong and it doesn't recognize my password.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be in quite a pickle. Since the email address is either invalid or does not belong to you, you probably want to call Apple to sort this out. If you have not used the account for anything. you could just set up as usual, but I'm guessing you already started using that account.

Go to [Apple ID Support](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/) for more info.